# How to replace the sender of an email sent by phpMailler

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have an SMTP webservice that sends emails from various applications. I use phpMailler to make these submissions. I use a GMAIL account to perform SMTP sending. When my client receives this email and opens it in their inbox, the sending server e-mail appears, in this case GMAIL. Is there any way to replace this email with another?

Comment: You can specify a different `From` address - but I am pretty sure Google is just going to overwrite this. A different mail provider might be less strict - but you’d probably not be doing yourself any favors with that anyway, because if you don’t have the rest set up properly in that regard (stuff like SPF), it will only increase the chances that those mails will be considered spam on the receiving end.

Answer (score 1):

With gmail, no. What you're asking for is usually considered forgery, and will be blocked by SPF record checks. Gmail does not allow you set arbitrary from addresses. You can preconfigure aliases within your gmail settings, but that doesn't let you add new address at send time and there are a limited number available.

You have some options though - ensure that the from address you're using *does* have appropriate SPF records to allow you to send from it, or live with the from address and set the reply-to address to point where you want replies to go - this is how [contact forms](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/contactform.phps) are usually configured, along the lines of:

```
$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'First Last');
$mail->addAddress('whoto@example.com', 'John Doe');
$mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);
```

Alternatively, if your sender addresses are set by users, then you need credentials for those email accounts so that you can send through them directly, rather than forging it through gmail.